# this.props.history.push does not redirect on first attempt

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, redux, mern

We are trying to redirect to a search results page once we have our results. We are using axios.get() to send the get request which follows:

```
export const searchPosts = (type, query) => async dispatch => {
    dispatch({ type: PARTIAL_LOADING, payload: false });

    const res = await axios.get('/api/search/',
    {
        params: {
            type: type,
            query: query
    }});

    dispatch({ type: PARTIAL_LOADING, payload: true });

    dispatch({
        type: SEARCH,
        payload: res.data
    });
};
```

We are trying to redirect to the next page using the following:

```
async submitSearch(values) {
  const type = values.type ? values.type : "Default";
  const query = values.query;

  if (type && query)
  {
    await this.props.searchPosts(type, query)
    .then(_ => {
      this.props.history.push('/search_results');
    });
  }
}
```

This redirects after the first attempt but will always fail the first time.

Comment: Can you use `await` and `.then` together? How does that work?

Comment: once you have the data on the success of getting request are you not able to route to the search results component, is the problem?

Comment: @DILEEPTHOMAS We can't and that's the problem.